Solving fractional partial differential equation with finite difference method
I am facing stack overflow error when I am trying to solve numerically the fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation using finite difference method in python.
This nonlinear partial differential equation (PDE) models how the envelope and phase of light pulse changes when propagating through a single mode optical fiber, when taking power attenuation ($\alpha$), group velocity dispersion ($\beta_2$)and waveguide nonlinearity ($\gamma$) causing self-phase modulation (SPM) into account.
The complete error code can be found here:
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:81: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return np.abs(amplitude) ** 2
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:109: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered 
in multiply
  return - 1j * (fiber.length / fiber.nonlinear_length) * np.exp(-fiber.alpha_dB_per_m * fiber.length * zeta) * getPower(pulseVector) * pulseVector
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:109: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  return - 1j * (fiber.length / fiber.nonlinear_length) * np.exp(-fiber.alpha_dB_per_m * fiber.length * zeta) * getPower(pulseVector) * pulseVector
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:136: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered 
in multiply
  K3 = (fiber.dz)**alpha * RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector + a22 * K2 + a21 * K1)
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:138: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered 
in multiply
  return pulseVector + w1 * K1 + w2 * K2 + w3 * K3
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:103: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide
  return ddy / (sim.time_step ** 2)
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:106: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered 
in multiply
  return 1j * (fiber.length / fiber.dispersion_length) * (1 / 2) * SecondTimeDerivative(sim,pulseVector)
c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py:134: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered 
in multiply
  K1 = (fiber.dz)**alpha * RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector)

Using finite difference method in the simplest way, I got stack overflow error. I realized that I can reshape the whole PDE into dimensionless form. With this I could theoretically solve the problem. I suspected that the problem was the too small time step. I also implemented the 3-stage fractional order Runge-Kutta integrator. But ultimately, the problem still persists.
The minimal reproducible code can be found here:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft, fftshift, ifftshift, fftfreq
from scipy.special import gamma

# constants
pi = np.pi
speed_of_light=3*1e8 # Speed of light [m/s]

# Defining parameters for the simulation
# Initialize Gaussian pulse parameters (OCTAVIUS-85M-HP from THORLABS) https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=OCTAVIUS-85M-HP
wavelength0=800*1e-9                                        # Pulse central wavelengt [m]
frequency0=speed_of_light/wavelength0                       # Pulse central frequency [Hz] 0.375*1e15 Hz = 0.375 PHz which equals to 800 nm
duration=8*1e-15                                            # Pulse duration in FWHM [s]
repetition_frequency=85*1e6                                 # Pulse repetition frequency [Hz]
average_power=600*1e-3                                      # Pulse average power [W]
pulse_energy=average_power/repetition_frequency             # Pulse energy [J]
peak_power=pulse_energy/duration                            # Pulse peak power [W]
amplitude=np.sqrt(peak_power)                               # Electrical field strength amplitude in units of sqrt(W)
N=2**10 #2**15                                              # Number of points                                                    
dt=0.01*1e-15                                                # Time resolution [s]
alpha=0.5                                                   # Fractional order

# Defining the parameters of the fiber
Length=1*1e-3 #5*1e-2                                                              # Fiber length [m]
nsteps=2**15                                                                       # Number of steps we divide the fiber into
effective_mode_diameter=5e-6                                                       # Effective mode diameter [um] from https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=780HP
effective_mode_area=(pi/4)*effective_mode_diameter**2                              # Effective mode area [m^2]
nonlinear_refractive_index=2.7*1e-20                                               # Nonlinear refractive index [m^2/W] of fused silica @ 800 nm from https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-27-26-37940&id=424534
gammaconstant=(2*pi*nonlinear_refractive_index)/(wavelength0*effective_mode_area)  # Nonlinear parameter [1/(W*m)]
beta2=36.16                                                                        # GVD in fs^2/mm (units typically used when referring to beta2) of fused silica @ 800nm from https://www.newport.com/n/the-effect-of-dispersion-on-ultrashort-pulses
beta2*=(1e-27)                                                                     # Convert GVD to s^2/m so everything is in SI units of fused silica @ 800nm
alpha_dB_per_m=0.2*1e-3                                                            # Power attenuation coeff in decibel per m. Usual value @ 1550 nm is 0.2 dB/km 

# Some useful parameters
nonlinear_length=1/(gammaconstant*peak_power)
dispersion_length=(duration**2)/(np.abs(beta2))

# Characteristic time, distance and amplitude scales
T = duration                                                                       # Characteristic time scale
Z = Length                                                                         # Characteristic propagation distance

# Defining a class for the simulation parameters
# Class for holding info about the simulation params
class SIM_config:
    def __init__(self,N,dt,duration,wavelength0):
        self.number_of_points=N
        self.wavelength0 = wavelength0                                             # Central wavelength
        self.duration = 1                                                          # Dimensonless
        self.time_step = dt /duration                                              # Dimensionless time step
        t = np.linspace(0,N*dt/duration,N)                                                                                  
        t = t - np.mean(t)
        self.t = t                                                                 # Dimensionless time grid
        f = fftshift(fftfreq(N,d=dt/duration))                                                                               
        self.f = f                                                                 
        #frequency0 = speed_of_light / wavelength0                                  # Dimensionless central frequency
        #self.frequency0 = frequency0                                               # Dimensionless frequency grid
        #f_rel = f + frequency0                                                                                      
        #self.f_rel = f_rel                                                        # Dimensionless relative frequency grid
        #wavelength = speed_of_light / f                                                                            
        #self.wavelength = wavelength                                              # Dimensionless wavelength grid
        #wavelength_rel = wavelength + wavelength0                                                                   
        #self.wavelength_rel = wavelength_rel                                      # Dimensionless relative wavelength grid

# Class for holding info about the fiber
class Fiber_config:
    def __init__(self,nsteps,length,nonlinear_length,dispersion_length,alpha_dB_per_m):
        self.nsteps=nsteps
        self.length = length
        dz = length / nsteps                                                       
        self.dz = dz / length                                                      # Dimensionless spatial step
        zlocs_array=np.linspace(0,length,nsteps)                                   
        self.zlocs_array = zlocs_array / length                                    # Dimensionless spatial grid                                   
        self.nonlinear_length = nonlinear_length
        self.dispersion_length = dispersion_length
        self.alpha_dB_per_m = alpha_dB_per_m 

# Defining Functions to simulate a Gaussian pulse
# Function returns pulse power or spectrum PSD
def getPower(amplitude):
    return np.abs(amplitude) ** 2
    
# Getting the spectrum based on a given pulse
def getSpectrumFromPulse(time,frequency,pulse_amplitude):
    dt=time[1]-time[0]
    spectrum_amplitude=fftshift(fft(pulse_amplitude))*dt # Take FFT and do shift
    return spectrum_amplitude

def getPulseFromSpectrum(time,frequency,spectrum_aplitude):
    dt=time[1]-time[0]
    pulse=ifft(ifftshift(spectrum_aplitude))/dt
    return pulse

def GaussianPulseTime(time,amplitude,duration):
    return amplitude*np.exp(-2*np.log(2)*((time)/(duration))**2)*(1+0j)
    #return amplitude*np.exp(-2*np.log(2)*((time)/(duration))**2)*np.exp(1j*2*pi*time*frequency0)

def SecondTimeDerivative(sim,pulseVector):
    ddy = np.zeros(pulseVector.shape, dtype=np.complex_)
    ddy[1:-1] = pulseVector[2:] -2*pulseVector[1:-1] + pulseVector[:-2] # boundary nodes are not included
    ddy[0] = 2*pulseVector[0] - 5*pulseVector[1] + 4*pulseVector[2] - pulseVector[3] # y'' at left boundary node (forward difference)
    ddy[-1] = -pulseVector[-4] + 4*pulseVector[-3] - 5*pulseVector[-2] + 2*pulseVector[-1] # y'' at right boundary node (backward difference)
    return ddy / (sim.time_step ** 2) 

def GVD_term(fiber,sim,pulseVector):
    return 1j * (fiber.length / fiber.dispersion_length) * (1 / 2) * SecondTimeDerivative(sim,pulseVector)

def SPM_term(fiber,zeta,pulseVector):
    return - 1j * (fiber.length / fiber.nonlinear_length) * np.exp(-fiber.alpha_dB_per_m * fiber.length * zeta) * getPower(pulseVector) * pulseVector

def RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector):
    return GVD_term(fiber,sim,pulseVector) + SPM_term(fiber,zeta,pulseVector)

def Euler(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector):
    return pulseVector + fiber.dz * RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector)

def RK4(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector):
    k1 = RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector)
    k2 = RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,fiber.dz/2*k1 + pulseVector)
    k3 = RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,fiber.dz/2*k2 + pulseVector)
    k4 = RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,fiber.dz*k3 + pulseVector)
    return pulseVector + fiber.dz/6 * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

def EFORK3(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector):
    # Precompute constants
    w1 = (8 * gamma(1 + alpha) * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)) / (3 * gamma(1 + 3*alpha)) - (6 * gamma(1 + alpha) * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)) / (3 * gamma(1 + 3*alpha)) + (gamma(1 + 2*alpha) * gamma(1 + 3*alpha) * gamma(1 + alpha) * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)) / (gamma(1 + 3*alpha))
    w2 = 2 * gamma(1 + alpha)**2 * (4 * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)**2 - gamma(1 + 3*alpha)) * gamma(1 + 2*alpha) * gamma(1 + 3*alpha)
    w3 = -8 * gamma(1 + alpha)**2 * (2 * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)**2 - gamma(1 + 3*alpha)) * gamma(1 + 2*alpha) * gamma(1 + 3*alpha)
    a11 = 12 * gamma(alpha + 1)**2
    a21 = gamma(1 + alpha)**2 * gamma(1 + 2*alpha) + 2 * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)**2 - gamma(1 + 3*alpha) * 4 * gamma(1 + alpha)**2 * (2 * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)**2 - gamma(1 + 3*alpha))
    a22 = -gamma(1 + 2*alpha)**4 * (2 * gamma(1 + 2*alpha)**2 - gamma(1 + 3*alpha))

    # We apply the Runge-Kutta method (modified for fractional derivatives)
    K1 = (fiber.dz)**alpha * RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector)
    K2 = (fiber.dz)**alpha * RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector + a11 * K1)
    K3 = (fiber.dz)**alpha * RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector + a22 * K2 + a21 * K1)

    return pulseVector + w1 * K1 + w2 * K2 + w3 * K3

# Defining the Simulation function
def Simulation(fiber:Fiber_config,sim:SIM_config,pulse,method):
    # Initialize pulseMatrix array to store pulse and spectrum throughout fiber
    pulseMatrix=np.zeros((fiber.nsteps, sim.number_of_points),dtype=np.complex128)

    # boundary conditions
    #pulseMatrix[:,0] = 0
    #pulseMatrix[:,-1] = 0

    # initial conditions
    pulseMatrix[0,:] = pulse
    
    # Initialize spectrumMatrix array to store spectrum throughout fiber
    spectrumMatrix=np.copy(pulseMatrix)
    spectrumMatrix[0,:]=getSpectrumFromPulse(sim.t,sim.f,pulse)

    # looping through space grid
    for m in range(fiber.nsteps-1):
        zeta = fiber.dz * m
        if method == 'Euler' :
            pulseMatrix[m+1,:] = Euler(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseMatrix[m,:])
        elif method == 'RK4' :
            pulseMatrix[m+1,:] = RK4(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseMatrix[m,:])
        elif method == 'EFORK3' :
            pulseMatrix[m+1,:] = EFORK3(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseMatrix[m,:])
        else :
            raise Exception(f'Unknown method {method}')
        spectrumMatrix[m+1,:] = getSpectrumFromPulse(sim.t,sim.f,pulseMatrix[m+1,:])
        delta = int(round(m*100/fiber.nsteps)) - int(round((m-1)*100/fiber.nsteps))
        if delta == 1:
            print(str(int(round(m*100/fiber.nsteps))) + " % ready")
    # return results
    return pulseMatrix, spectrumMatrix

# Initialize class about simulation parameters
sim_config = SIM_config(N,dt,duration,wavelength0)

# Initialize Gaussian pulse in the time domain
testPulse = GaussianPulseTime(sim_config.t,amplitude,sim_config.duration) / amplitude

# Initialize class about fiber
fiber = Fiber_config(nsteps,Length,nonlinear_length,dispersion_length,alpha_dB_per_m)

# Run Dimulation
pulseMatrix, spectrumMatrix = Simulation(fiber,sim_config,testPulse,'EFORK3')

def plotFirstAndLastPulse(matrix, sim:SIM_config):
  t=sim.t
  plt.figure()
  plt.title("Initial pulse and final pulse")
  power = getPower(matrix[0,:])
  maximum_power=np.max(power)
  plt.plot(t,getPower(matrix[0,:])/maximum_power,label="Initial Pulse")
  plt.plot(t,getPower(matrix[-1,:])/maximum_power,label="Final Pulse")
  #plt.axis([-5*sim.duration,5*sim.duration,0,1])
  plt.xlabel("Time [arbitrary unit]")
  plt.ylabel("Power [arbitrary unit]")
  plt.legend()
  #savePlot('initial and final pulse')
  plt.show()

plotFirstAndLastPulse(pulseMatrix,sim_config)

The expected behavior looks like this, but with different time scaling.
EDIT
By adding the following lines of code:
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")

I could finally get the traceback from the warnings:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py", line 186, in <module>  
    pulseMatrix, spectrumMatrix = Simulation(fiber,sim_config,testPulse,'EFORK3')
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py", line 166, in Simulation
    pulseMatrix[m+1,:] = EFORK3(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseMatrix[m,:])
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py", line 138, in EFORK3    
    K3 = (fiber.dz)**alpha * RightHandSide(fiber,sim,zeta,pulseVector + a22 * K2 + a21 * K1)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py", line 114, in RightHandSide
    return GVD_term(fiber,sim,pulseVector) + SPM_term(fiber,zeta,pulseVector)
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py", line 111, in SPM_term
    return - 1j * (fiber.length / fiber.nonlinear_length) * np.exp(-fiber.alpha_dB_per_m * fiber.length * zeta) * getPower(pulseVector) * pulseVector
                                                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Balazs\Desktop\kutatás\fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation\simulation_v1.12\main.py", line 83, in getPower
    return np.abs(amplitude) ** 2
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^~~
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square

EDIT2: Some important techniques with references that I used in this simulation:

The nonlinear Schrödinger equation (for optics) can be derived from the wave equation. However we can choose between two (Fourier transform) notations. The derivation with the negative one can be found in Ursula Keller's book. I used this, because the scipy library uses the negative convention for the DFT.
The derivation of the dimensionless transformation for the nonlinear Schrödinger equation can be found here.
The 3-Stage Explicit Fractional Order Runge-Kutta Method algorithm in Mathematica can be found here.
I converted my original code into vectorized form. With this the code "runs" in O(mlog(n)) time instead of O(mn).


I recommend a Math forum. Floating point iteration is notorious instable (approximation errors). The error says normal (numerical) overflow, not stack overflow = endless calling oneself. You should try debugging to see what exactly happens . I think. Good luck.

You need to provide a traceback of where it failed and what the error actually was. Making everything double precision might buy you enough headroom to avoid trouble. Several algorithms that are completely robust in double precision will go AWOL in single float precision unless you are incredibly careful.

@JoopEggen Maybe you are right, eventually this is mainly a (numerical) a math problem, but also a programming one. Actually, I saved the solution array in a csv file. What I saw was monotonically increasing large numbers with NAN and INF values ​​at the end. This means that the solution explodes in finite time.

@MartinBrown Traceback added.

OK. My first guess is that you may have a normalisation problem or a division by nearly zero that allows the amplitude to grow unbounded with each iteration. ODEs with exponentially decaying target solutions can be inclined to suffer from parasitic exponentially growing solutions if not handled very carefully. You need a decent reference book on the technique(s) you are trying to use.

@MartinBrown I studied this book in my spare time. This is very useful in most (and "simple") cases, however my case is very special.

My suggestion would be simplify the problem to the barest bones and then build up the complexity again step by step until it fails to solve. If I was trying to do this I might be tempted to use a Chebyshev polynomial matrix formulation of the problem. I think you need to find a book that deals with this specific class of problem or someone with domain expertise to guide you. It is a research problem beyond what can sensibly be fixed here. Try asking on the physics or mathematics groups you might get lucky (read the posting guidelines first)

@MartinBrown I added the concept of the time window (1000 fs). Then I normalized the quantities accordingly. With this I was able to work with the Euler and the 4th order Runge-Kutta integrators. However the problem with the Fractional integrator still persists. The results can be found here. Now I am facing another issue: how can I define the (normalized) wavelength quantity? I will definetly ask somebody, who is experienced in this field. Thanks for the suggestions so far.

@MartinBrown I did some observations when I ran the code with different conditions. The time grid is fine enough, when N >= 2^12. When the N variable is below 2^13, this works perfectly with the RK4 or Euler integrators. When the N variable is below 2^7, the fractional integrator works perfectly.
